# Error pip install mariadb on ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, mariadb

I try to install the mariadb module with `pip install mariadb` but it error like this.

```
Collecting mariadb
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/73/250a30543f9987af2e3f7856f29917fa22580cd6b457b8e2df0d6d80b3f3/mariadb-1.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.1.5, found version 3.0.3
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 2 in /tmp/pip-build-f3yri8cs/mariadb/
```

And what i have try is run `pip install --upgrade setuptools` then `pip install mariadb` but it still not working, so how can i fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.1.5, found version 3.0.3`
Install the correct version of the MariaDB Connector/C
https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-c/3.1.5/

Comment: Thank you for response, but is that have any tutorial to install mariadb with the version, i'm very new with ubuntu.

Answer (score 13):

I found the solution for this problem:
So, to run pip install mariadb, I followed these steps:

I'm using python3.9, instead of olders versions,

Installing Python 3.9:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.9
```

Installing Pip3:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Adding repo of mariadb:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
curl -LsS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash
```

If you receive some problens with apt-transport-https, install this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
```

Run these updates:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now, you can install the newest Connector/c:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb3
sudo apt-get install libmariadb-dev
```

Finally, you can run:

```
sudo pip3 install mariadb
```

Should work just fine, sorry for the long post.

Comment: In my case, I had to `sudo apt install python3.9-dev` as well.

Comment: whoever troubled to write such a long explanation deserves a credit.
Worked like a charm! Thanks to you,

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! As for the `dist-upgrade` commands, I didn't use them.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said the version in ubuntu:18.04 isnt recent enough.

I got this working in bionic.

```sh
mkdir -p /tmp/mdbccbin
cd /tmp/mdbccbin

curl -O https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.1.10/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-ubuntu-bionic-amd64.tar.gz

echo "1b5b513f44967efadf5eae5e34952cd61f94655575d45b5a9182ea1b91d1d1fa  mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-ubuntu-bionic-amd64.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c

# get root
sudo su

tar xvf mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-ubuntu-bionic-amd64.tar.gz --directory /usr --strip-components 1

echo "/usr/lib/mariadb/" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mariadb.conf
ldconfig

# back to regular user
exit

python3 -m pip install --user mariadb
```

Comment: `WARNING:` This is for AMD64, and not ARM64. I misread it as arm64, and followed the steps to install the binary on my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a newer version of MariaDB Connector/C. Since you have an older ubuntu version (which doesn't provide an actual version of MariaDB Connector/C) you need to download it from MariaDB website.

Since MariaDB Connector/C 3.1.8 MariaDB provides also binary packages for non EOLed Ubuntu platforms. Actual version is 3.1.9 and can be downloaded [here](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.1.9/)

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the followings:

```
sudo apt purge libmariadb3 
sudo apt purge libmariadb-dev
```

(It seems removing one also removes another.)

After downloading [MariaDB Connector/C](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/) and un`tar`ing it, you can find three directories; `bin`, `include`, and `lib`. They get what you need to `pip install`.
If you try `pip install mariadb` before you do the followings, you will figure out what to put where by yourself, as I did.
What I figured out is:

```
sudo mv -f bin/mariadb_config /usr/bin/
sudo mv -f include/mariadb    /usr/local/include/
sudo mv -f lib/mariadb        /usr/local/lib/
```

Now you may `pip install mariadb`, however, you may not `import mariadb`.
Then, you need:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/mariadb/
```

Answer (score 1):

Building mariadb connector from source (v3.3.1).

```
wget https://archive.mariadb.org//connector-c-3.3.1/mariadb-connector-c-3.3.1-src.zip
unzip mariadb-connector-c-3.3.1-src.zip
cd mariadb-connector-c-3.3.1-src/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

Now pip install should run without any errors.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall mariadb
sudo pip3 install mariadb
```

Note that `pip3 install mariadb` may pass even when the connector dependency isn't satisfied, hence uninstall it first via `pip3 uninstall mariadb`

Sometimes the prebuilt binaries may not be available for the version and platform configuration you want.

`OS: Raspbian 11 (bulls eye) aarch64` for Raspberry PI 
For x86 or x64 architectures, you can simply get prebuilt binaries, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64556085/981766).

You can get source code for a particular connector version [here](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=connector&p=connector-c&r=3.2.7&os=source).
You may have to select the checkbox for displaying older releases if the release you are looking for isn't being shown.

[image: display older releases]

Comment: Just the bit of shell commands at the top of this answer has fixed this issue on Debian 11 for me.