# Uninstall BUILT mariadb-connector for python

Tags: mariadb, python-3.11, mariadb-connector

I recently started to have some problem with mariadb in python and i decided to upgrade my connector since on another machine its running fine.

Any idea how i can uninstall the connector?

Tried:
I installed python 3.11 and followed this to install the new connector: found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64556085/9442848)

```
mkdir -p /tmp/mdbccbin
cd /tmp/mdbccbin

curl -O https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.1.10/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-ubuntu-bionic-amd64.tar.gz

echo "1b5b513f44967efadf5eae5e34952cd61f94655575d45b5a9182ea1b91d1d1fa  mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-ubuntu-bionic-amd64.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c

# get root
sudo su

tar xvf mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-ubuntu-bionic-amd64.tar.gz --directory /usr --strip-components 1

echo "/usr/lib/mariadb/" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mariadb.conf
ldconfig

# back to regular user
exit

python3 -m pip install --user mariadb
```

It didnt work, i still had the error: 'ImportError: MariaDB Connector/Python was build with MariaDB Connector/C 3.3.5, while the loaded MariaDB Connector/C library has version 3.3.4.'

So i installed it the way i originally installed the connector ([found in the thread as above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76983710/9442848)):

```
wget https://archive.mariadb.org//connector-c-3.3.1/mariadb-connector-c-3.3.1-src.zip
unzip mariadb-connector-c-3.3.1-src.zip
cd mariadb-connector-c-3.3.1-src/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

I still got the error "ImportError: MariaDB Connector/Python was build with MariaDB Connector/C 3.3.5, while the loaded MariaDB Connector/C library has version 3.3.4." when doing pip install mariadb.

Comment: i also tried sudo make uninstall mariadb-connector-c-3.3.1-src
make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.

I tried to find the make folder with this with root in the whole computer: find . -type d | grep mariadb-connector-c-3.3.1-src

Comment: Why do you download C/C 3.1 when 3.3 is required?

Comment: i had it installed way back when it was new